# How do I add song to iTunes' "Up Next" with Applescript

Tags: applescript, itunes

I'm pretty new to Applescript (literally just started today), but I can not find out how to just play an album without having to create a playlist with only one album and play that playlist. Essentially I've figured out how to search for what I want and play something, but I can only play one song at a time.

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set search_results to (search playlist "Library" for "Monument Valley (Original Soundtrack)")
    repeat with i in search_results
        play i
    end repeat
end tell
```

If I do this, it runs through every song until it hits the last one and the last one is played. I believe you can use `next track` in order to add something to the "Up Next", but I haven't gotten it to work. Is there a way to actually do this or do I have to succumb to playing a playlist?

Comment: Putting a comment here because this isn't really a fully-fledged answer, but the Shortcuts app now has partial access to the Up Next queue (which it calls Playing Next).  It lets you "clear" and "add", although not inspect the queue.  You can invoke this from AppleScript by calling the `shortcuts` command line tool, and … somehow … supply it with input via the `--input-path` command line argument.  You will need to make your own shortcut though, because I don't think `shortcuts` can invoke anything you haven't added to your shortcuts app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, the iTunes AppleScript dictionary has **no "terminology" for the Up Next queue**. Even [Doug's AppleScripts for iTunes](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/index.php), the iTunes scripting authority, has no scripts for Up Next. The `next track` command is just to "advance to the next track in the current playlist"— equivalent to pressing the "next" button. It seems **the only way to script Up Next would be to use GUI scripting**, meaning you would tell AppleScript which buttons in the Graphical User Interface to click instead of using an API. This can be quite difficult, so I think you'll have better luck if you **just succumb to using playlists**. Fortunately, the iTunes dictionary does include plenty of controls for creating and manipulating playlists.

Comment: AppleScript still does not support Up Next queue. However, it is supported in the Shortcuts app.